# Why is the layout/rendering phase periodic?

Tags: javascript, html, css

as shown by the Safari debug tools?

In the image below you can see that the layout / rendering is periodic, this acutally extends out to 12 seconds or so but the image is cut off.

I can post any other relevant info.

[image].

Looking into it further there is a large table that divides Layout/Rendering into three operations:

`Layout, Paint, ReCalculate Styles`

Looking further I can see that they are all paint operations.

of an area of 3px by 13px all at the same x / y coordinate of 1169px and 189px

Comment: A possible reason that comes to mind is because of any ajax calls that may be invoked during layout render causing the rendering to differ while the call waits for the data.

Comment: ... well the bizarre thing is that is is the same exact 3px by 13px space ...

Comment: Do you use any special plugins? E.g. the jQuery resize plugin causes such patterns.

Comment: 3px by 13px. Sound to me like an animated gif.

Comment: I don't have any animated gifs though.